# Javascript function reference to an array input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in a form with `id`'s that are repeating as array items. Here is one row from the table:

```php
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="data[]" id="data[]" onkeyup="updates_toggle(this);" value="<?php echo($item['data']); ?>" size="40" maxlength="100"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="VAT_in[]" id="VAT_in[]" onkeyup="updates_toggle(this);" value="<?php echo($item['VAT_in']); ?>" size="8" maxlength="10"/>
        <input type="hidden" size="1" name="updates[]" id="updates[]" value="0"/>
   </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updates_toggle(this_ref){
        if(ups=this_ref.???????????('updates[]')){
            ups.value="1";
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I want the `updates_toggle()` JavaScript function to update the hidden `updates[]` value to "1" for that row; so that I can update the database later (just for the items changed) when the form is submitted.

How do I pass an appropriate reference and/or how do I refer to the correct instance of `updates[]` in my JavaScript without using jQuery?

Comment: The more care you take in making your question informational and readable the more interest you will get, I have tidied the question up a little, but just remember for next time please.

Comment: I tried to go back in and edit but you had already jumped in. Thanks.

Comment: This is invalid HTML. You have an INPUT element hanging inside a TR element. Also, PHP and the TABLE have nothing to do with your question. Why did you include them?

Comment: Please show your attempts at the function.  Otherwise you're asking us to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: both versions require the "simple" table structure*

```
<tr>
    <td>[inputs]</td>
    <td>[inputs]</td>
    <td>[inputs]</td>
    [...]
</tr>
```

*For deeper structures refer to @user1690752 for looking up the parent tr and "recursions" for searching your updates[].*

**Version for a structure with a fixed number of inputs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updates_toggle(self) {
        var element = self.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[2];
        element.value = 1;
    }
</script>
```

This requires

```
updates_toggle(this)
```

If the number of input fields changes, you'll have to update the function accordingly.

**Version for a structure with an arbitary number of inputs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updates_toggle(self) {
        var elements = self.parentNode.parentNode;
        var element = searchingChilds(elements.childNodes);
        if (element) {
            element.value = 1;
        }
    }

    function searchingChilds(tr) {
        for (var element in tr) {
            var subelement = tr[element];
            if (subelement.nodeName === "TD") {
                for (var subtd in subelement.childNodes) {
                    var subsubelement = subelement.childNodes[subtd];
                    if(subsubelement.nodeName === "INPUT" && subsubelement.attributes.id.value === "updates[]") { 
                        return subsubelement;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;    
    }
</script>
```

PS: Just something from the top of my mind, your request (and this is way beyond a simple question) is so vague that i considered not writing anything.

On the one side other developers could chime in and say, this doesn't work in all cases (and of course it doesn't there is a reaeson ppl use jQuery) on the other you could remember something along the lines of "yeah wait.. i need it for yet another structure, could do this for me".

Don't abuse SO for cheap workpower, think yourself about your problems (you already got all pieces in the first round of answers) and put some effort in your questions.

Comment: I can see this could work for this specific instance but I want a way to explicitly reference the updates[] field to avoid the problem you mention. I want the function to work with any form table on my website where I make updates to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
    updates_toggle() 
to 
    updates_toggle(dataId). 
You can then pass the input element to the function:

```
onKeyUp="updates_toggle(this);"
```

In your function you could then identify the closest parent element of the type **tr** and within this tag find the hidden field. With jQuery this would look something like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val(1);
```

With plain JavaScript the function looks as follows:

```
function updates_toggle(field) {
var p = field.parentNode;
    while(p.tagName != 'TR') {
        p = p.parentNode;
    }
    var oldVal = p.children[1].children[1].value;
    p.children[1].children[1].value = oldVal + 1;
}
```

I solved your example here (I cleaned the code a little bit): http://jsfiddle.net/Tfk3C/2/

Comment: jQuery is neither listed as a `tag` and is not an option as mentioned in the question. So why doint you change all that jQuery `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val(1);` to just `this.nextSibling`?

Comment: Yes was trying with 'this' but can't get it to work. Please note I am not using jquery. Do you have a non-jquery solution?

Comment: **+1** For the improvements. It's gone back to 0 because i never downvoted. it was someone else.

Comment: This could work but is position dependent. I want a solution that specifies updates[] as the target.

Answer (score -1):

put this in your updates_toggle()

```
document.getElementById("updates[]").value = 1
```

Comment: There aere multiple updates[] input fields. I want to update the version in the row that I have edited. See update code above.